# Django Auth: "This field is required"

Tags: django

I want to integrate my own form to the django Auth system. It throws always an error:

> login This field is required. password This field is required.

Setting an Debug-Point on `if request.method == 'POST':` didn't worked (except on page starting/loading).

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Immo.ImmoUser'
```

ImmoUser class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ImmoUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="index" method="post" style="/*! height: 100%; */margin-top: 20%;">
  <img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'Immo/images/houses.png' %}" style="background-color: black; padding: 5px;border-radius: 10px;" alt="" width="72" height="72">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>

  {% csrf_token %}

     {{ form.errors }}
  <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.username.auto_id }}">{{ form.username.label }}:</label>

     <input id="{{ field.username }}" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:3px;" autofocus="" placeholder="Login*" required="" type="text">


  <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.password.auto_id }}">{{ form.password.label }}:</label>
     <input id="{{ field.password }}" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:3px;" autofocus="" placeholder="Password*" required="" type="password">


  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def mylogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            return redirect('Immo/user/index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'Immo/index.html',  {'form': form} )
```

**EDIT:** 
This works:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="index" method="post" style="/*! height: 100%; */margin-top: 20%;">
  <img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'Immo/images/houses.png' %}" style="background-color: black; padding: 5px;border-radius: 10px;" alt="" width="72" height="72">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>

  {% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.errors }}
  <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.login.auto_id }}">{{ form.login.label }}:</label>

     <input name="login" id="{{ form.login.auto_id }}" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:3px;" autofocus="" placeholder="Login*" required="" type="text">


  <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.password.auto_id }}">{{ form.password.label }}:</label>
     <input name="password" id="{{ form.password.auto_id }}" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:3px;" autofocus="" placeholder="Password*" required="" type="password">


  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the attribute **name** in your `inputs`:

```
 <input name="username" ...>

 <input name="password" ...>
```